# Write a system call as a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I have been given an assignment to "Write a system call as a kernel module". Now as far as I could understand from my reading on the internet, it is not exactly possible to implement a system call as a kernel module, however there are ways to intercept the existing system calls. Is this the right way to do it ?
I found one such example on this blog: http://syprog.blogspot.in/2011/10/hijack-linux-system-calls-part-i.html

Answer (score 2):

In linux sys_call_table contains function pointers for all system calls. This table was initially exported back in the days of 2.4 , then it was made static , then again it was exported in of some of latest kernels.Lets take example of two cases.

***Case 1. sys_call_table exported.***

Use following line in your kernel module.

*sys_call_table[AVAILABLE_INDEX] = new_sys_call;*

New system call can be implemented as.

*asmlinkage new_sys_call(...) { }*

***Case - 2)  sys_call_table not exported.***

Try getting sys_call_table address by grepping in System.map

**$cat System.map|grep sys_call_table**

Hard code the value in your module.

If that is not available , then we need to determine the table address dynamically.
sys_call_table most likely be there in the beginning of kernel text section.

Here are steps to compute base address of sys_call_table

1. Find two system calls which are placed next to each other in the
       table(from source code).    For ex: sys_read , sys_open.
2. Get address of these sys calls.
3. Search these two addresses from the beginning of text section.

   (Compute start of text section by , objdump -h vmlinux|grep ".text")
4. When you found it , compute the base of sys_call_table , based on
   their relative offset.